# Understanding what host means in Docker

Tags: docker

I was just trying to experiment around with some docker commands, particularly the `-v` command. I see the below command in the documentation for docker.

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

The following explanation is provided:

> This will mount the host directory, /src/webapp, into the container at
>   /opt/webapp.

I fail to understand the initial part , I.E. `This will mount the host directory, /src/webapp`, , what does `host` mean in this scenario/context ? can somebody explain ? I am having a real hard time understanding what host mean , can anybody explain ?

The Documentation can be found **[HERE](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Host" generally means "the physical computer on which you are running Docker" (or other virtualization service).

In your example, `-v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp` will expose the `/src/webapp` directory on the computer running Docker inside the `web` container as the directory `/opt/webapp`.